# getting error in test class "System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object"

Tags: trigger, unit-test, failing-tests

getting error in test class

> "System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object"
>
> "Class.TesttriggeronoppandquoteUpdate.myUnitTest1: line 13, column 1"

i have created this test class for trigger. Dont know what i am missing here..please help me out...

```
@isTest
public class TesttriggeronoppandquoteUpdate {
static testMethod void myUnitTest1() {

    Account a = new Account();
    a.Name = 'Test';
    insert a;
    system.debug('a: '+a);

    opportunity op = new opportunity();
    op.Name = 'test1';
    op.StageName = 'Nurture';
    op.CloseDate = system.today();
    op.AccountId = a.id;
    insert op;

    Pricebook2 p = new Pricebook2();
    p.Name = 'Test';
    insert p;

    OpportunityLineItem opl = new OpportunityLineItem();
    opl.OpportunityId = op.id;
    opl.Quantity = 20;
    opl.UnitPrice = 30;
    opl.Discount_Amount__c = 40;
    opl.PricebookEntryId = p.id;
    insert opl;

    opportunity opp = new opportunity();
    opp.id = opl.OpportunityId;
    opp.SubtotalNew__c = opl.Quantity * opl.UnitPrice;
    opp.Discount_valueNew__c = opl.Discount_Amount__c;
    opp.TaxNew__c = 12;
    insert opp;

    Quote q = new Quote();
    q.Name = 'Test';
    q.SubtotalNew__c  = opp.SubtotalNew__c;
    q.Discount_AmountNew__c = opp.Discount_valueNew__c;
    q.TaxNew__c = opp.TaxNew__c;
    insert q;

}

static testMethod void myUnitTest2() {

    Account a = new Account();
    a.Name = 'Test1';
    insert a;

    opportunity op = new opportunity();
    op.Name = 'test2';
    op.StageName = 'Nurture';
    op.CloseDate = system.today();
    op.AccountId = a.id;
    insert op;

    Pricebook2 p = new Pricebook2();
    p.Name = 'Test';
    insert p;

    OpportunityLineItem opl = new OpportunityLineItem();
    opl.OpportunityId = op.id;
    opl.Quantity = 10;
    opl.UnitPrice = 40;
    opl.Discount_Amount__c = 60;
    opl.PricebookEntryId= p.id;
    insert opl;

    opportunity opp = new opportunity();
    opp.id = opl.OpportunityId;
    opp.SubtotalNew__c = opl.Quantity * opl.UnitPrice;
    opp.Discount_valueNew__c = opl.Discount_Amount__c;
    opp.TaxNew__c = 22;
    update opp;

    Quote q = new Quote();
    q.Name = 'Test1';
    q.SubtotalNew__c  = opp.SubtotalNew__c;
    q.Discount_AmountNew__c = opp.Discount_valueNew__c;
    q.TaxNew__c = opp.TaxNew__c;
    update q;

}
}
```

Comment: The error specifies the line number in trigger too along with test class line number. Can you specify what statement does your trigger have at that line so that i could solve your issue.?

Comment: error is on TesttriggeronoppandquoteUpdate test class....and on this line "op.Account.id = a.id;"

Comment: to assign the account id to opportunity use this op.Account = a.Id;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update line 13 as below

```
op.AccountId= a.id;
```

This will solve your issue. Dont forget to accept answer if it works..Tia

Comment: hey i did it thanks anyways...but now recieving FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION  error.. i am updating code

Comment: post a seperate question to get it addressed